# Using for-loops along a data frame column when defining a function in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dataframe, calculated-columns

I would like to define a function that adds a new column to a data frame and computes its entries by looping over the entries of an existing column. It shall always subtract the entry of the current row from the entry of the following row. The new column shall be called `y`:

```
example_df <- data.frame(x = runif(10))
fun <- function(df, a, b) {
  df[, b] <- rep(NA, length(df[, a]))
  for (i in 1:(length(df[, a]) - 1)) {
    df[, b[[i]]] <- df[, a[[i + 1]]] - df[, a[[i]]]
  }
  return(df)
}

fun(example_df, "x", "y")
```

This shall return the data frame with a new b column with computed entries for all rows but the last one, which should be `NA`. 
However, I get the following message returned:

```
Error in a[[i + 1]] : subscript out of bounds
Called from: `[.data.frame`(df, , a[[i + 1]])
```

I cannot figure out the problem, but guess that the indexing somehow doesn't work. I'm thankful for all the help provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a for loop to do this. You can use the `mutate` and `lead` functions from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)

example_df <- data.frame(x = runif(10))

example_df %>% 
  mutate(y = lead(x, 1) - x)
```

that will give you this:

```
           x          y
1  0.3873464  0.2171617
2  0.6045081  0.3849549
3  0.9894630 -0.1876334
4  0.8018296 -0.3385969
5  0.4632327 -0.2864295
6  0.1768032  0.5489654
7  0.7257686 -0.2135999
8  0.5121687  0.4478171
9  0.9599858 -0.5048904
10 0.4550954         NA
```

Comment: Wow, that's easy, thanks a lot! I should definitely take a closer look into the dplyr package.